# Get clicked element in ButtonSet

Tags: jquery

I would like to know which element is clicked so I can change its CSS class. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
       $("#radio").buttonset();
      });
</script>
```

---

```
<div id="radio">
   <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
   <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
   <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

jQuery events returns `this` as the object which fired the event. So you just have to check `this`.

Having this set of elements

```
<div id="radio">
   <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
   <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
   <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
</div>
```

Select all radio elements:

```
$("#radio :radio")
```

Then bind an event:

```
.click(function(e) { });
```

Retrieve the element with `this`:

```
$("#radio :radio").click(function(e) {
    var rawElement = this;
    var $element = $(this);

    /* Do stuff with the element that fired the event */
});
```

**[Example on jsFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/hJnjw/)**

You can [find here functions](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=class&go=) to manipulate the element's class.

Comment: What does this part mean: `var $element = $(this);`?  How is `$element` different?  What would you do with that?

Comment: @jeffamaphone `this` is the DOM node. `$(this)` is the jQuery object which contains the DOM node

Answer (score 5):

You can also retrieve the selected radio button out of the buttonset using:

```
$j("#radioset :radio:checked")
```

then do whatever you want with the element...

Comment: I am curious about what "$j" means or is that a typo ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like:

```
$("#radio :radio").click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("id")); // this refers to current clicked radio button
   $(this).removeClass('class_name').addClass('class_name');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#radio :radio").click(function(){
    //alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#radio').bind('click', function(event){
       $('#radio').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#radio').buttonset().find(':radio').click(function(e) {
    var $radio = $(this);
    $radio.addClass('active');
});
```